# WEINRE : how to debug my app over the WAN (on a machine that is oustide my LAN)

Tags: web-applications, weinre

I am using Weinre to debug my hybrid app. Is it possible to get the console logs from an app on machine that is outside of my LAN ?
Maybe by putting my global IP in the script call instead of using my local IP :

```
<script src="http://GLO.BAL.IP:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

and by forwarding the 8080 port to my local IP my my router configuration...?

Thanks
ps: by the way, if there is another solution than Weinre that can allow to do this, I will be glad to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself :

indeed, just forward the port 8080 to your local machine.
When you call the weinre script, use your global ip:

```
<script src="http://GLO.BAL.IP:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

then go to your browser and open :

```
http://GLO.BAL.IP:8080/client/#anonymous
```

see here : http://gilesey.wordpress.com/tag/weinre/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [run a weinre server on the public internet yourself](http://pmuellr.blogspot.com/2012/11/weinre-installable-at-heroku-and-behind.html), or use an existing weinre server on the public internet, like http://weinre.mybluemix.net/